# Как закрепить за датой числа?

Tags: php

Например

```
за 01.01 закрепить числа от 1 до 10,
за 02.01 закрепить числа от 11 до 20,
за 03.01 закрепить  от 21 до 30
итд.
```

Опишу ситуацию. Пользователь вбивает данные в форму, выбирает дату в календаре и в БД заносится номер(уникальный в выбранном месяце) + за датой должно быть закреплено, например, 10 номеров (на следующий день  номер уже должен начинаться с 11).

Написал такой скрипт(увеличивает номер на 1 + каждое первое число месяца присваивает номеру 1):

```
if($selectstate['datestate'] != $dates&&($arrDate[0] == 1)) {
    $numberWay=1;
    $datestate = date('dm');
    $sql = "UPDATE state SET datestate = (:datestate);";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(['datestate'=>$datestate]);
} else {
    $numberWay++;
}
```

Comment: RegEx в помощь. Нужно составить RegEx для валидных значений и проверять

Comment: @Игорь Петров а что такое "закрепить числа"? какая задача решается?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: дата по сути это число. если на каждую дату надо закрепить 10 значений, то умножьте эту дату на 10, и плюсуйте +1..9 к ней

Comment: Все так как сказал @teran только плюсуйте count записей из базы за указанную дату

Comment: получилось, спасибо. Но теперь другая проблема. Нужно чтоб нумерация 1 числа каждого месяца начиналась опять с 1.

Comment: Понял. Из $count вычесть кол-во записей и так каждое первое число)